# How to make sure child method instantiates child instead of parent object?

Tags: php, oop, late-static-binding

I have a parent and a child class as below

```
class Objet {

    ../..

    static function findByNumeroDeSerie($table, $numeroDeSerie) {
        $db = new Db();
        $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * from $table WHERE numeroDeSerie = :numeroDeSerie");
        $query->bindValue(':numeroDeSerie', $numeroDeSerie, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->execute(); 
        while($row = $query->fetch()) {
            return new Objet($row);
        }
    }
}


class Produit extends Objet {
    // 
}
```

When I call method `Produit::findByNumeroDeSerie($table, $numeroDeSerie)`,

```
$produit = Produit::findByNumeroDeSerie("produits", $_GET['numeroDeSerie']);
echo get_class($produit); // echoes Object
```

it instantiates an `Objet` instead of a `Produit`, which means I can't access the getter methods of `Produit` on the instantiated object.

Any idea why? Do I need to rewrite the *findByNumeroDeSerie* method in every child class of Objet ?

Comment: There's no way for the instantiation to be dynamic ?
the code of the child method will be identical to the parent, it seems like it would defeat the purpose of parent and child :)

Comment: I've edited the end of my question to explain better (so you can understand where I'm trying to instantiate a Produit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote:

```
return new Objet($row);
```

So you have Object. If you want `findByNumeroDeSerie` to return Product use `get_called_class()` function like this:

```
<?php

class A {
    static public function foo() {
        $className = get_called_class();
        return new $className();
    }
}

class B extends A {

}

var_dump(get_class(B::foo())); // string(1) "B"
```

Answer (score 1):

Much simpler, just use `static` and "[late static binding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)".

```
class TheParent {

    public static function build(): TheParent
    {
        return new static();
    }
}

class Child extends TheParent {}

$child = Child::build();
$parent = TheParent::build();

echo get_class($child), "\n"; //
echo get_class($parent), "\n";
```

[Output](https://3v4l.org/RBZjZ):

> Child
>
> TheParent